# Vertical color status Bar (Index)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

This is first questions so learning how too use the stackoverflow too.

I would like to show the color value in Android like image attached. 
This is just to show the color status.(This is not for selection).
Simple color index with approprite value (Text or number).

[image]

Comment: just to show the color status.(This is not for selection). then just put the image itself.

Comment: Thanks. But the color value will be coming from the server.

Comment: oops ok. if the number of values is fixed create a layout accordingly else create the view dynamically and set the color as BG ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AA3456"));
```

Maybe you need this.
or Try to create a custom xml layout and the use `setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AA3456"));`

Comment: Tnx..I will check and revert